# How to find an example of $\sigma(x)$ given that $\tau(x, \sigma (x) ) = \cos(\log( x -1 )$ and that $\tau$ is symetric?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have two functions $\sigma$ which is involutive and $\tau$ which is symmetric, and I also have that the function $f$ is given by

$$f(x) = f(\sigma(x)) $$

I've already proven that

$$ f(x) = \tau(x, \sigma(x)) $$

and I also showed that $\frac{x}{x - 1}$ is an possible example of $\sigma$ in the case where : $ f(x) = \tau(x, \sigma(x)) $

I need to find examples of $\sigma(x)$  where :

$$f(x) = \frac{x^4}{x^2 - 1}$$ and  $$ f(x) = \cos(\log(x - 1)) $$

I'm stuck on how to find such examples ? Also I'd love to see how the reasoning would work in this case

All functions here, are real functions of real variables .

Comment: Your question as written seems unclear (and not directly related to the title): is the question to find functions $\tau,\sigma$ with $\tau$ symmetric and $\sigma$ involutive satisfying $\tau(x,\sigma(x))=f(x)$ for various $f$? Also, are all the functions in question real functions of real variables? (i.e. $\tau:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $\sigma:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$)

Comment: @user1306 Thank's for pointing this out, I've made some edits, to make my question more clear .

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure what the parameters of the question are, but I'm assuming that you want to find a function $\tau,\sigma$ as above satisfying $\tau(x,\sigma(x))=f(x)$ for the stated functions. I am not sure this is correct though, since as far as I can tell, you essentially always want to just take $\sigma$ to be the identity function and artificially replace $x^n$ with $x^{n/2}y^{n/2}$.

For $\tau(x,\sigma(x))=\frac{x^4}{x^2-1}$, you can take $\tau(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{xy-1}$ and $\sigma(x)=x$. Then $\tau(x,\sigma(x))=\frac{x^2\sigma(x)^2}{x\sigma(x)-1}=\frac{x^2\cdot x^2}{x\cdot x-1}=\frac{x^4}{x^2-1}$ as required.

For $\tau(x,\sigma(x))=\cos(\log(x-1))$, you can take $\tau(x,y)=\cos(\log(\sqrt{xy}-1))$ and $\sigma(x)=x$ once again.